# Warning: Failed to restore: downloadCache failed: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to use `actions/cache@v3`.

GitHub Enterprise Server 3.8.8

Cache was created successfully with a separate workflow:

```yaml
      - name: "Skopeo cache"
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: /usr/local/bin/skopeo
          key: binaries-${{ github.ref }}
```

When I try to restore it with another workflow in the same branch and the same key I get the message:

```
Warning: Failed to restore: downloadCache failed: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Workflow logs:

[image: workflow logs]

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

To resolve this issue I set environment variables like:

```yaml
 env:
   GH_ENTERPRISE_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
   GH_HOST: 'git.custom-host.com'
```

which didn't provide any influence.

Comment: Have you shown this to your system administrator? Looks like the certificate chain is not loaded completely. Apart from that, the cache lookup is a miss as indicated in the next log.

Comment: Did you find the cause of this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: In my case, cache usage was blocked (not updated) by the runners' management team.